# T-SQL Syntax error: Column 'dbo.Policy.CompanyId' is invalid in the select list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Could someone help me figure out what's wrong with the following T-SQL syntax?

```
SELECT 
    p.CompanyId, COUNT(*) as PolicyCount, c.CompanyId, c.CompanyName
FROM 
    dbo.Policy p
    INNER JOIN dbo.Company c ON p.CompanyId = c.CompanyId
WHERE 
    p.PolicyIssuingDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY
    p.PolicyId
```

I keep getting the following syntax error:

`Column 'dbo.Policy.CompanyId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

Ok thanks to your input guys, I figured it out... Here's the solution:

```
SELECT 
    p.CompanyId, COUNT(p.PolicyId) as PolicyCount, c.CompanyName
FROM 
    dbo.Policy p
    INNER JOIN dbo.Company c ON p.CompanyId = c.CompanyId
WHERE 
    p.PolicyIssuingDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY
    p.CompanyId, c.CompanyName
```

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: @MartinSmith: I understood the error message, but I do not understand the reason behind it. I guess that's some basic SQL concept that I do not know about (I'm new to T-SQL, I've always used LINQ to Entities in the past).

Comment: It really does tell you everything you need to know! I considered answering but realised that essentially all I would be doing would be rephrasing the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your query u are trying to count records which have same policyID and whose issue date is between @startdate and @enddate
But the problem is u select companyid which is not in group by clause

Comment: all the fields use in select clause should come in group by clause also

Comment: hmmm... what I really want is to get the count of policies issued by each company between start and end dates. So basically, my query will not produce the result I'm looking for, right?